# Enable native zoom on only one page

Tags: cordova

Hi i have a web app and i want to enable zoom in specific page

When i add this code :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    cordova.plugins.ZoomControl.ZoomControl("true");
    cordova.plugins.ZoomControl.setBuiltInZoomControls("true");
    cordova.plugins.ZoomControl.setDisplayZoomControls("true");
}, function(){
    alert('error deviceready');
});`
```

and that i leave the page specific page, zoom is enable on all the pages..

I using jquery mobile on phonegap build and this plugin :

https://github.com/kumbe/Phonegap-ZoomControl/blob/81f15e3/README.md

Comment: Many/most cordova apps I have seen or written are in effect single-page apps, so an option may be adding and removing your `document` event listener as you change pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok, i put the zoomControls at "false" in the main.js

and each page i put it with zoomControls at "true" AFTER the main.js